# render a simple static JSON response using Play! and Java

Tags: java, json, playframework

I have this function to return a valid JSON response:

```
public static Result response() {
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();        
    result.put("status", "OK");
    result.put("response", "Hello ");
    return ok(result);        
}
```

But what I want is to server an Array of objects in "result" property like:

```
{
   "status": "OK",
   "response": {
      "results": [
         {
             "key1": "value",
             "key2": 90,
             "key3": "value"
         },
         {
             "key1": "value"
             "key2": 90,
             "key3": "value",
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I do this? I need to use Java and Play!

Answer (score 2):

The Play framework uses Jackson. Therefore, you may use Jackson proper:

```
private static final JsonNodeFactory NODE_FACTORY = JsonNodeFactory.instance;

// ...
final ArrayNode results = NODE_FACTORY.arrayNode();
ObjectNode oneResult;

oneResult = NODE_FACTORY.objectNode(); // or Json.newObject();
oneResult.put(...); // etc
results.add(result);

//rinse, repeat for all other result objects, then:
result.put("results", results);
```

I guess the `Json` class also has `.newArray()` and such. Have a look at Jackson's `ObjectNode`, `ArrayNode`. Note: as far as I can remember, Play uses Jackson 1.9.x, which is prehistoric...

But really, you should try and use Jackson's {de,}serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I did not wait for your answer about what is Play!, so I write based on Gson.
Try use this class:

```
public class Result implements Serializable {
    String status;
    Response response;

    class Response implements Serializable {
        List<ListItem> results;

        class ListItem implements Serializable {
            String key1;
            Integer key2;
            String key3;
        }
    }
}
```

It 100% works on your json fragment. You can supplement it with the necessary fields.

And then you can use Gson:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
Result result = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(new File("json.json")), Result.class);
String json = gson.toJson(result);
System.out.println(json);
```

Prints:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "response": {
    "results": [
      {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": 90,
        "key3": "value"
      },
      {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": 90,
        "key3": "value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Try in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

How about returning an `ArrayNode` in the result, like:

```
public static Result foo() {
    ArrayNode arrayNode = Json.newObject().putArray("bars");
    arrayNode.add("hello");
    arrayNode.add("world");
    return ok(arrayNode);
}
```